# Update undefined error for mean-stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am having a problem with some of my mean stack code.   The code is shown below along with the error I am receiving.  Dos anyone have any suggestions.  It seems to be a simple declaration error but I can not seem to find a solution

```
    customersApp.controller('CustomersUpdateController', ['$scope', 'Customers', '$log',
    function($scope, Customers, $log) {
        // Update existing Customer
        this.update = function(updatedCustomer) {
            var customer = updatedCustomer;
            customer.$update(function() {
            $log.info('Made it inside ok');
                //Dont want to take user anywhere else
//              $location.path('customers/' + customer._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$update' of undefined
at update (http://localhost:3000/modules/customers/controllers/customers.client.controller.js:115:12)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10880:21
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10655:29
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:441:9
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12788:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12886:23)
at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:440:13)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:2853:10
at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
```

I also get an error {Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToggleElement' of null} on the load of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever outside code that is calling the `update` function is either not passing in an argument, or it is passing in a variable that is undefined.

```
Cannot read '$update' of undefined.
```

refers to `customer.$update`. It means that `customer` is undefined. It receives its value from whatever argument is passed in for the`updatedCustomer` parameter, so you need to trace back what you expect to be passing in for `updatedCustomer`.

Is the external code that calls this `update` function in fact passing in an argument at call time?

Comment: thanks...  Found the problem.  I just needed to put customerUpdateCtrl.update(customer); when all I had was customerUpdateCtrl.update();.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary, the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToggleElement' of null
```

comes from ui-bootstrap and causes no critical errors.

It refered as an issue here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2343

It is related to the dropdown menu.